# How do I convert an eclipse java project into an application software that can be simply run on a system?

Tags: eclipse

I have an simple java project with a little UI also. I need to convert the entire project into an software which can be ri=un on any system.( Preferably win 7 and win 8).

Thank You in advance

Comment: "Any system", you have to go with executable .jar; Windows systems, you can go the .exe route.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project in the package explorer, then click export. Select java in the list, and select as a Runnable Java Jar.

Here's a video that shows you step by step: [Export Java program](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RbhJ9sTMTD8)

This goes a bit more in depth about the export options you have. [Here](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/import_export/)

Comment: Thank you!! It really is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The .jar file that is created for your app can be run on any system with the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) installed but if you want to have an installer like any normal software, try downloading nsis https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/, a software that helps you create an installer for your app so that users can install it just like any normal software.

Comment: Thank you, it works as required by me.